# how to fetch a webaddress from file in an angular webapp

Tags: angular, typescript

I have recently been tasked with maintaining an angular typescript web application. In order for my company to release it, it will need a file in which necessary web addresses are specified. A config file that can be filled out and read without recompiling the project. 
However, I have no prior experience with Angular.

I've tried to add the config file to assets and grab the web address with a singleton class using a html get request. However, the get request fails to deliver the the web address in time.
To clarify the situation, the angular application needs the web address immediately once it is opened, as it is depended on a web api.

Code in singleton class:

```
        await this.getAdress().subscribe(result =>{
           this.apiAddress = result["Address"];      
       });
     }
         getStringAdress() {       
         return this.apiAddress;
     }
```

The singleton is initiated from one of the first accessed pages and the getAsyncData is called. This page performs another http request where the url is getStringAddress(), which fails as the address returned is undefined.

Is there a better way to go about getting variables from a config file, or do I use promise instead of subscribe. If I have to use a promise how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same technique over and over again with the `config.json` in the assets and it is working just fine.

I think the service you are using is injected later in time in some component that is not initially created on application boot.

Make sure to add your service at `app.component.ts` even if you are not using it at the component because this will trigger the Angular injector to create an instance of the config service you have at application boot.

The services in Angular are lazy so the instance of each of them will be created only when they are called in a component, directive or another service.

Comment: For some reason this is still too slow, the first page that is accessed performs a request to the external API immediately.

Comment: If the request is been invoked outside Angular(Angular zone), then you have to go with a different approach and store the config with pure javascript before the request is executed and access the config from angular on app boot e.g. in the `ngOnInit` of `app.component`. If this is not the case I guess you will need to do a cache like service where if the `config` is not received you have to store all calls and when the config is received to execute all cached calls.

Comment: for now I've solved it using a timeout of 10 ms. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, this will do the trick until the user using the application have a bad network connection and the response with the config come 10ms later.